# Conditionally replace elements in PHP 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, optimization, execution

Currently, i am using the following code to replace the elements of an array which are greater than the `$value`

```
for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++) {
            for($j=0;$j<$column;$j++) {
                if($solution[$i][$j] >= $value) {
                    $solution[$i][$j] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a better and faster way to do it? I have a complex algorithm to generate the puzzle and i am trying to optimize the execution time. This code is a part of the algorithm.

EDIT:

These are the execution times that i get by trying different solutions:

```
For loops:

4.1007995605469E-5

Answer by mark:

0.00057792663574219

Foreach loops:

2.9087066650391E-5
```

Comment: How long is it taking, and how long do you want it to take?

Comment: Just want to know, if array elements can be replaced without looping them. I don't know the execution time exactly.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without doing benchmarks. Please do them and compare with solutions using `array_walk()`, `array_map()` and other functions.

Comment: So, your current solution would run in O(n^2). To do better than this, we would probably need to understand when `$value` is known relative to when `$solution` array is built. For example, can you make the replacement as the array is being populated?

Comment: $solution is 4x4(can be upto 9x9) is prefilled with values(eg: 4X4 may contain values from 1 to 16). At a later stage in the algorithm i backtrack and need to replace the values of $solution to -1(which is the initial value of all the elements in the array).

Comment: If the arrays are unordered, you will have to examine every node regardless to know whether every node fits/doesn't fit the criteria.  If it's possible to sort the arrays as you are populating them, you can cut out traversing nodes as soon as you hit one that is less than $value.

Comment: i can't sort the array as the sequence in which the elements are populated is important.

Comment: Would it be possible then to store the data twice as you're populating?  One set would be the data, as you want it to be ordered, the other would be the data ordered descending, but also stores the index pairs of where it should appear in your 2d array.  This would take more storage, but less processing.

Comment: yes i can do that. Thanks for your suggestion @Kai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $solution, 
    function(&$aVal, $key, $value) {
        $aVal = ($aVal >= $value) ? -1 : $aVal;
    },
    $value
);
```

but you'll need to benchmark

Comment: Ok i will try it out.

Comment: Fundamentally this won't change the fact that this is O(n^2) execution time, though it may be faster than a PHP loop because you would be using underlying C looping.

Comment: I tried the solution and used microtime() to calculate the execution time. This is slower than the regular PHP for loop.

Comment: @MikeBrant - the underlying C looping may be faster; but the cost of the callback may negate that

Comment: You could also test nested `foreach()` loops with value `by reference`

Comment: Nested foreach() loops  with value by reference are slightly faster. Thanks Mark!